# Fetching date format from file to append to a filename in Android

Tags: android

How can I get DateFormat MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss to save my photos name?

```
fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/CameraExample/" ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Time t = new Time();
t.setToNow();
String session = t.format("%D %T")) //Strftime format

File f = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
String fullfilename = f.getAbsoluteFile() + "/Android/data/Photos/" ;

File fileToWrite_data = new File(fullfilename,session + "_Data.txt");
FileOutputStream fos_data = new FileOutputStream(fileToWrite_data,true);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php

Comment: Thanks a lot, I mean not from the file, sorry for the bad English). I did so -       SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd"+"." + "MM" +"." + "yyyy" +"_"+ "HH" + "-"+ "mm" + "-" + "ss");
      fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/CameraExample/"  + sdf.format(new Date())  + ".bmp");